# Pass array in --extra-vars

Tags: yaml, ansible

How can I pass YAML array to `--extra-vars` in Ansible playbook?

I mean if I have a playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ hostName }}"
  remote_user: admin
```

Then I should call my playbook like

```bash
ansible-playbook DeployWar.yml \
  --extra-vars="hostName=tomcat-webApp"
```

But I want to run this playbook on two servers say `tomcat-webApp` and `tomcat-all`, and I want to control it from outside, i.e.: using `--extra-vars`.

What I have tried to do is:

```bash
ansible-playbook DeployWar.yml \
  --extra-vars="hostName=[tomcat-webApp, tomcat-all]"

ansible-playbook DeployWar.yml \
  --extra-vars="hostName={tomcat-webApp, tomcat-all}"

ansible-playbook DeployWar.yml \
  --extra-vars="[{hostName: tomcat-webApp}, {hostName: tomcat-all}]"
```

But in all cases my playbook fails declaring a syntax error in my call.

Answer (score 61):

To answer your first question, *"How can I pass YAML array to `--extra-vars` in Ansible playbook."*: you can pass a [JSON formatted string to `extra-vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime).

Here is an example play:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        var: test_list
```

And how to pass the variable `test_list` to the command `ansible-playbook`:

```bash
ansible-playbook \
  test.yml \
  --connection local \ 
  --inventory localhost, \ 
  --extra-vars='{"test_list": [1,2,3]}'
```

Though you can use a variable for hosts I recommend checking out Ansible's mechanism for host management which is [inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html) in conjunction with the `--limit` option.

Comment: Whenever I'm working with JSON, whether in extra-vars or elsewhere I find the use of http://jsonlint.com to be a lifesaver. By pasting {test_list: [1,2,3]} into that site you can quickly verify that your JSON is syntactically correct.  It's especially useful when passing multiple variables to Ansible or when you have any other complex JSON you're working with.

Comment: @jarv a great reason to use `--limit` over host variables is that if you accidentally leave out `--limit`, the playbook will execute over ALL of your hosts, which may get YOU fired but is great for job security for your replacement.

Comment: @BruceP [`jsonlint`](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint) may also be installed locally as a CLI command, which is preferable for sensitive JSON, and even more convenient in certain use cases, e.g. redirecting compact JSON into it to prettify the JSON.

Comment: You can do the same without creating a playbook file with this command : `ansible -i localhost, all -m debug -a "var=test_list" --extra-vars='{"test_list": [1,2,3]}' `

Comment: I generally use jq for checking syntax. Not same as a linter, I know. I like jq because it does filtering and so is very useful. A null '.' filter shows me if the json is syntactically correct. stedolan.github.io/jq.   The yaml tool `spruce` is equally useful for merging, diffing, etc.  Since it has a --json option, the two work together. https://github.com/geofffranks/spruce

Answer (score 13):

As of Ansible 1.3, extra vars can be formatted as YAML, either on the command line or in a file. See [the Ansible documentation titled Defining Variables At Runtime](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime).

Example:

```
--extra-vars "@some_file.yaml"
```

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps, don't try to pass complex types via command line and handle their creation within the playbook from json files or strings.

So, @NelonG's approach works but how will it work in all execution contexts?  My playbooks tend to get executed by Jenkins jobs via ansiblePlaybook and via packer.   Getting the following to work in all of those (even when the command line looks right) doesn't work and can lead to an escaping nightmare.

```
ansible -i localhost, all -m debug -a "var=test_list" \
--extra-vars='{"test_list": [1,2,3]}'
```

How about passing in as a string and then splitting via set_fact (note: this only works if you have elements without problematic characters.  I have URLs so they are reasonably safe

```
ansible .... -e "test_list_csv=1,2,3,http://foo.bar/file.txt"
```

In the playbook

```
name: generate list from string
  set_fact: 
    test_list: "{{ test_list_csv.split(',') | list }}"
```

I decided to escape from escaping and it seems to work.

Comment: Thank you SO much!  For days I've been trying to figure out how to pass a list in JSON format from Jenkins to Ansible using the ansibleplaybook module whose extraVars requires a map.  And here I stumble onto your answer.  It's so simple but totally solves my issue:  don't pass it in JSON, pass it it as a comma-separated value in a map.  Thank you SO much!

Comment: @PaulFernandez I totally feel your pain.  FYI If you aren't yet using a jenkins shared library and https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit then take a look at both.  They moved life from replay & hope to actual TDD

Comment: thanks for the shared library recommendation!  I hate to do this in a comment thread but I can't message you directly so...do you have any good resources for Jenkins Groovy, specifically for scripted pipelines?  I basically try to do everything three ways:  the Apache Groovy way, the Java way, and then finally the Jenkins Groovy way, which I stumble into only because the first two didn't work.  I'm frustrated with the lack of clear documentation when it comes to scripted pipelines.  Thanks again!

Comment: @PaulFernandez  you can tweet at me  at citizenkahn   The CPS stuff used by jenkins presents a challenge as many reasonable actions cease to be so.  I've moved to a docker container running python executing groovy closures to avoid some of those nuances

Answer (score 5):

In addition to answer from *jarv*, here is my savior note:

In case someone wants to pass in an **array of integers**, this works:

```
--extra-vars '{"my_params":[40,50,10,20,30]}'
```

**Note**: there should be ***no space*** in between the numbers in the array you pass! Removing space solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use jinja j2 template to fulfil the requirement

```
my j2 template
----------------------------------------------------------------------
[all_hosts]
{% for ip in my_serverlist.split(',') %}
host ansible_host={{ip}} ansible_connection=ssh 

{% endfor %}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------


playbook task
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
- name: Generate and copy inventory file
  template:
    src: inventory.j2
    dest: "ansible/INVENTORY"
    mode: 774
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

command
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ansible-playbook generate-inventory-file.yml --extra-vars 'my_serverlist=1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way to pass yaml directly to the extra-vars:

- use a namedpipe in form of `<(command)`
- then take it like a file, so you need the `@` sign
- to take valid yaml, you just use `echo "multiline yaml"`

all together:

```sh
ansible-playbook DeployWar.yml \
  --extra-vars=@<(echo "
hostName:
- tomcat-webApp
- tomcat-all
")
```