# ansible-playbook --extra-vars host array or single host

Tags: ansible

Can you pass a json array: `--extra-vars "{server: [bo-121.q.net,mer-122.q.net,mer-123.q.net]}"` to the host var?  I want the playbook to work for one or many hosts.

It is my first boot tasks that runs on all hosts.

playbook yml:

`- hosts: "$server"`

Comment: [this doesn't help me with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617273/pass-array-in-extra-vars-ansible)

Comment: You can pass an array of hosts and set it with `- hosts: "{{ server }}" - but all hosts have to be available in the inventory.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood the question correctly I think you can accomplish this by giving host names or groups as command line. E.g. if I want to deploy the staging server only:

```
 ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini playbook.yml --limit staging
```

`hosts.ini` is

```
 [default]
 staging ansible_ssh_host=x.x.x.x ansible_ssh_user=x
```

Answer (score 1):

`ansible-playbook mesos.yml --extra-vars "cluster=mesos1"`

mesos.yml

`- hosts: '{{ cluster }}'`

group / host needs to be in your inventory file.