# Ansible-Playbook passing lists for specific tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-2.x

[Much like this question regarding passing an array mine is a bit different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617273/pass-array-in-extra-vars-ansible)

The OP, was trying to give the play multiple hosts to run on.

Fails clearly. My goal is to "loop" through my play on each account within my `.boto` configuration file. Sure I could leverage a simple bash loop. But was thinking to do something more with Ansible, by passing specific "acct" vars into it. *Updated with task that fails.

```
- name: Ansible Roles in AWS .v01
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    role_state: present   
    dict1: { "dev", "mgmt", "uat", "sbx" }
  # - debug: var=
  tasks:
  - name: hhc-ADMIN-Role-Create
    with_items: dict1
    tags:
      - admin
    iam:
      iam_type: role
      region: us-east-1
      profile: "{{ item }}"
      name: hhc-{{ dict1 }}-ADMIN
      state: "{{role_state}}"
      trust_policy_filepath: ./Policies/Trust/Role-Trust-Policy.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method to utilize a "list" would be the following:

```
---
- name: Ansible Roles in AWS .v01
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    role_state: present   
    list:
      - { profile: "dev", role:  "ADMIN" }
      - { profile: "dev", role:  "MGMT" }
  tasks:
  - name: hhc-ADMIN-Role-Create
    with_items: "{{ list }}"
    tags:
      - admin
    iam:
      iam_type: role
      region: us-east-1
      profile: "{{ item.profile }}"
      name: hhc-{{ item.profile }}-{{ item.role }}
      state: "{{role_state}}"
      trust_policy_filepath: ./Policies/Trust/Role-Trust-Policy.json
```

This will create a role of ADMIN and MGMT in Dev. There has got to be a more elegant way to do something like

```
list:
  - { profile: "dev", role: [ "ADMIN", "MGMT"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to set `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable in the loop.

Pseudo code:

```
  tasks:
    - ec2: ... ....
      environment:
        AWS_PROFILE: "{{item}}"
      with_items: cli_var
```

Comment: Sure I will give that a go and see what happens, thanks for the help sir! Will report back my success or failure.

Comment: I think I am on the right path... I updated my question with a sample play it has the prior components that work with hardcoded components.

Comment: Still not able to use cli_var as I would like hmmmmm.

Comment: I am Reading The Functional Manual here. :) http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control