# Deploy multiple VMs from an OVF file

Tags: ansible, vsphere

I am trying to develop the code for creating multiple VM's using module deploy ovf in Ansible. I've tried to find out with other solution, but, it didn't work out. Here you can see my playbook :

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - vars: vars.yml
  tasks:
      - name: deploy ovf
        vmware_deploy_ovf:
          hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
          username: "{{ username }}"
          password: "{{ password }}"
          validate_certs: "{{ validate_certs }}"
          datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
          name: "{{ vm_name }}"
          ovf: "{{ ovf_path }}"
          cluster: "{{ cluster }}"
          wait_for_ip_address: true
          inject_ovf_env: false
          power_on: no
          datastore: "{{ datastore }}"
          networks: "{{ vcen_network }}"
          disk_provisioning: thin
```

In variables files, I set "vm_name" as list.

```
vars.yml
vm_name:
        vm-01
        vm-02
```

So I've ran the code with extra variables like this:

```
ansible-playbook main.yml -e "vm_name=vm-01" -e "vm_name=vm-02".
```

It's only create vm-02 but not for both. Also, I tried to use "loop" or "with_items", but, it didn't work out.
Please assist, thank you

Comment: `-e "vm_name=vm-01" -e "vm_name=vm-02"` => here you are setting the same variable twice. So your last definition wins. Make the `vm_names` a JSON array: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25625887/2123530

Comment: I did make the vm_names a JSON array and running the playbook like this:
"ansible-playbook main.yml --extra-vars '{"vm_names": ["vm1","vm2"]}' -vvv

However, in the center, It's only creat 1 vm with name : ['vm1', 'vm2']. Could you help?

Comment: Well, off course, you also have to loop, now you have a list, as you described it in your description.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support, I nailed it

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.  Don't do that.  Have the hosts in your inventory, and let Ansible do its thing:

```
- hosts: all
  become: no
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - vars: vars.yml
  tasks:
      - name: deploy ovf
        vmware_deploy_ovf:
          # hostname: "{{ hostname }}" # use environment variables
          # username: "{{ username }}" # use environment variables
          # password: "{{ password }}" # use environment variables
          validate_certs: "{{ validate_certs }}"
          datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
          name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          ovf: "{{ ovf_path }}"
          cluster: "{{ cluster }}"
          wait_for_ip_address: true
          inject_ovf_env: false
          power_on: no
          datastore: "{{ datastore }}"
          networks: "{{ vcen_network }}"
          disk_provisioning: thin
        delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you be more specific about it?

Comment: I assume `vars.yml` has a list of the hosts you want to build.  Make that list an inventory file.

Comment: Thank you, I got your point. I have one question, after following your advice, I'm able to deploy multiple VMs. However, the name will match with "inventory_hostname" => dynamic name. Basically, all the VMs are using the same network.
If I would like to deploy with different network item, is it possible we could do that like (name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"). Or we have to edit vars.yml and hard code it

Comment: Put that into the inventory, too.  Best to group the VMs according to network and put that info into `group_vars` files.

Comment: Thank you so much, I nailed it